# webview not working correct?

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

I open my web view in an another activity without using default browser, by using webview client but, but when I click on the icons in the website it will not work

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.highlights);
        WebView a = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        CustomWebViewClient myCustomWebViewClient = new CustomWebViewClient();
        a.setWebViewClient(myCustomWebViewClient);
        a.loadUrl("http://www.google.co.in/");
   }
```

there will be a different url instead of google but when i click on link of any other web address it will not work.

Comment: enable javascript webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: visit http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/webview/android-webview-example/

Comment: Do you get any error in logcat? What is 'du'?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
du.loadUrl("http://www.google.co.in/");
```

to

```
a.loadUrl("http://www.google.co.in/");
```

Also, remember to have INTERNET persmission in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and enable Java script:

```
a.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement the method `ShouldOverrideUrlLoading` to do that

```
private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And add this to Your Code

```
a.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
```